# Nodejs app is continuously restarting

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I have a nodejs app running on a number of Raspberry Pis that is interacting with Firebase. I use Forever to keep the app running.

For some of the Pis it sometimes happens that the app is continuously restarting until I reboot the Pi.

What would be a good strategy for debugging such a problem?

Comment: Run your app without `forever` and see what error causes your application to stop running.

Comment: Check if there is no exception that arise.

Comment: I also recommend to check out Joyent's best practices for error handling post at https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors to get a better idea on how to catch unhandled exceptions that can cause the app to restart.

Comment: There is no error in the log. But running the app without Forever is still very good idea.